# Prove that $\{\frac{p}{q} \in (a,b) \cap \mathbb Q : \frac{1}{q} \ge \epsilon\}$ is a finite set

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume that we write every rational number as $\frac{p}{q}$ such that
>   $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ and $q \ge 1$.   Define a function with takes a
>   rational number as input and gives the inverse of its denominator as
>   output. Now, take every arbitrary $\epsilon \gt 0$ and an arbitrary
>   open interval like $(a,b)$.
>
> Prove that $\{\frac{p}{q} \in (a,b) \cap \mathbb Q : \frac{1}{q} \ge
>  \epsilon\}$ is a finite set.

Note : I have no idea how to prove that a set is finite. It would be great if someone showed me how to deal with this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that if $\epsilon > 0$ is given, $1/q \geq \epsilon$ implies $q > 0$ and $q \leq 1/\epsilon$, so there are only finitely many integers such $q$. Can you conclude that for each of these choices of $q$, there are only finitely many integers $p$ such that $p/q \in (a,b)?$

Answer (score 1):

For a given $\epsilon$, having $\frac{1}{q} \ge \epsilon$ means that $q$ must be bounded above by $q \le \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ so you only have finitely many $q$. Now since all the $\frac{p}{q}$ must be in a bounded interval, you can only have finitely many $p$ as well (or else the ratio would grow arbitrarily large).